# Vb.net unzip programme

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write an program to extract zipped files using vb.net. I am facing a problem - when I try to extract the files, it ask fro replacement agreement, but I need  to extract that files without asking for my an agreement.

This is the code I use:

```
Dim shObj As Object =        Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"))
Dim outputFolder As String = appPath
Dim inputZip As String = appPath + "\patchFile.zip"
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder)

    'Declare the folder where the items will be extracted.
    Dim output As Object = shObj.NameSpace((outputFolder))

    'Declare the input zip file.
    Dim input As Object = shObj.NameSpace((inputZip))

    'Extract the items from the zip file.
    output.CopyHere((input.Items), 4)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can use the second parameter of CopyHere to respond Yes To All for any dialog box displayed and it should avoid your dialog box.

```
output.CopyHere((input.Items), 16)
```

Edit :

And if you still need option 4 to not show progress, you can combine both so it would be 20 instead of 16

Comment: thank you ver much but i have another question after extract processes done , i need to make statement with if , to do function after extraction process

Comment: Knowing that CopyHere is async, I don't think there is an embedded way to do it but you can take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042801/how-to-check-when-shell32-folder-copyhere-is-finished

It seems to be two alternative ways to accomplish it